# WordPress Customizer API - Toggle second checkbox if first is selected: Not saving

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 checkboxes. When 1 is selected then the other one is un-checked. I have used JS to accomplish this and it works fine. But then when I click save, the option that is un-checked does not get saved. If I actually un-check the checkbox with a mouse click then it does save. What's the best way to accomplish the above situation?

PHP Action and JS that I am using:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', 'my_customizer_custom_scripts' );

function my_customizer_custom_scripts() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* This one shows/hides the an option when a checkbox is clicked. */
    jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox1 input').click(function() {
        if (jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox2 input:checked').val() !== undefined) {
            jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox2 input').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });

    jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox2 input').click(function() {
        if (jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox1 input:checked').val() !== undefined) {
            jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox1 input').attr('checked', false);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out have to use `trigger('click')` instead of the `attr('checked', false)`.

So

```
jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox1 input').attr('checked', false);
```

Becomes

```
jQuery('#customize-control-checkbox1 input').trigger('click');
```